# How to append element of same index from a list to another list multiple times?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists of equal lengths as follows

```py
list1 = ['23, 42, 52', '4, 3, 6']
list2 = ['foo', 'bar']
```

How do I make a single list with the desired outcome be:

```py
list = ['23foo, 42foo, 52foo', '4bar, 3bar, 6bar']
```

I have tried:

```py
list= [i + j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

but this gives an output:

```py
list = ['23, 42, 52foo', '4, 3, 6bar']
```

Comment: len(list1) = 2
len(list2) = 2

Comment: @LeiYang they are the same length, note `list1` is two strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want:

```py
list3 = [', '.join((f"{i}{j}" for i in k.split(', '))) for k, j in zip(list1, list2)]

print(list3)

['23foo, 42foo, 52foo', '4bar, 3bar, 6bar']
```

Because you need to split up the first string before you can add the desired suffix to it. Then, re-join the split string together.

Also, try not to shadow `list`, it's a built-in, so `list3` is a better name for it